# Increment XML parameter on click

Tags: javascript, xml, loops, parameters, parameter-passing

I have an rss feed which has a FeedLimit parameter of 5

I want to put a button at the bottom which says "View Next Five"

In order to do this I imagine I need an `href` with some javascript embedded which will set FeedLimit = FeedLimit+5

Although from my research it seemed as though the only way to increment XML parameters is within a loop.

The segment of my code is below, and you'll notice there is a ToggleItemDescription, which shows/hides a description for each item..this was my inspiration but it is code which was generated by SharePoint

```
<xsl:param name="rss_FeedLimit">5</xsl:param>
  <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:param name="Rows"/>
<xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
  <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
  <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
  <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
  <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
    <div class="item link-item" >
      <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
          <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
            <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="title"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </a>
      <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
        <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
          <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
        <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
          <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </div>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<div class="description">
  <h4 class="ms-rteElement-H4B">
    <span class="ms-rteStyle-Emphasis">
      <br></br>View More Articles&#160;<img alt="more-icon-1.png" src="/BHiveImageGallery/Stock-Images/more-icon-1.png"/>
    </span>
    <span class="ms-rteStyle-Emphasis"> </span>
  </h4>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, it seems that XML / XSL does not allow you to overwrite a parameter/variable value after it has been written.

I am unsure whether the functionality I was requesting is possible.. you could possibly iterate through multiples of 5 and store each as its own parameter.. but in the end it was decided to show a full list rather than increment the current display so this answer was not needed.

The inability to overwrite parameter values makes this a quite tricky problem to have